# How did my calculation become Erronous?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

So I have this node voltage equation problem.  Seems really easy, actually.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs7TT9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In fact, this appears to be only one equation, barring constants.
$$\frac{1}{110}v_{12}+(2)\frac{20}{10}+\frac{1}{100}v_1=0$$ with the fairly obvious addition of \$v_2=20\$.

This [works out](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%201%2F110%28v1-v2%29%2B%282%29%2820%2F10%29%2B%281%2F100%29v1%3D0%20and%20v2%3D20) to be \$v_1=200\space\mathrm{v}\$.

However, the book says the answer is 219 volts.  What is the error in my approach?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you made a mistake. It seems like you only have three terms in your sum, but there are four legs. Is that part of the problem? I actually think this is a hard problem, but I graduated from college over 10 years ago. Let me walk you through it.

I am going to sum all the currents going into V2. Just have to calculate them first, and write them with the correct polarity (going INTO V2).

i_1 is -2A by inspection.
So 2*(i_1) is -4A.
Current in the Voltage source is V1/100 +2A (going up... this itself is a sum)
Current in the 110 Ohm is (V1-20)/110 (going to right in 110 Ohm resistor)

So, summing currents into node, -2A -4A +2A + V1/100 + (V1-20)/110 = 0.
V1/100 + (V1-20)/110 = 4
V1/100 + V1/110 - 20/110 = 4
V1/100 + V1/110 = 4+20/110
V1 (1/100 + 1/110) = 4 + 20/110
V1 = (4 + 20/110)/(1/100 + 1/110)
V1 = 219.05.

Hope that helps.